# how to change folium/geojson color

Tags: python, geojson, folium

i wish make it different color in different layer,
so use the style_function as i googled like below:

```
style1 = {'fillColor': '#228B22', 'lineColor': '#228B22'}
style2 = {'fillColor': '#00FFFFFF', 'lineColor': '#00FFFFFF'}

test1=gpd.read_file('file2.geojson')
folium.GeoJson(test1,name='test1',style_function=lambda x:style).add_to(mainmap)

test2=gpd.read_file('file1.geojson')
folium.GeoJson(test2,name='test2', style_function=lambda x:style2).add_to(mainmap)
```

however,it does not work on the line, still the default blue.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/4awkXVi

Comment: What happens if you use `'color'` rather than `'lineColor'`?

Answer (score 8):

a simple way to do so is to replace

```
style1 = {'fillColor': '#228B22', 'lineColor': '#228B22'}
style2 = {'fillColor': '#00FFFFFF', 'lineColor': '#00FFFFFF'}
```

by

```
style1 = {'fillColor': '#228B22', 'color': '#228B22'}
style2 = {'fillColor': '#00FFFFFF', 'color': '#00FFFFFF'}
```